# CodeIgniter - Get Last URI Segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the last URI segment in CI, however I don't know what the number for it will be, as parameters (an integer) will be appended as the user clicks links within the page. These are then used in a controller to pull relevant database records into the page via ajax.

How can I tell CI to get the last segment?

Something like:

```
$record_num = $this->uri->segment($last);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, both answers are good. I've gone Anpher's as it's a bit more concise.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$record_num = end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

Comment: hi! i used this code but when the segment is not found then it's throw error please help. i write in if condition with empty but not work.

Comment: always declare your parameter like `public function name($parameter = " ")`

Comment: `Only variables should be passed by reference`. Use Mischa answer instead.

Answer (score 33):

This should work:

```
$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
$record_num = $this->uri->segment($last);
```

Comment: +1 I like this method better, since it uses codeigniter's functionality. It just seems like the right thing to do.

Comment: I agree, like this one better. You can save yourself a line too: $record_num = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());

Answer (score 4):

I needed this in 2021 and here's how I got to it

```
$record_num = end($this->uri->segments)
```

Ty to Anpher that got me in the right track

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$last_segment = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
echo $last_segment;
```

Above code is for English language, for UTF8 such as Arabic, Persian, etc use :

```
$last_segment = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
echo urldecode($last_segment);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with CodeIgniter 4.

```
// Instantiate CI request
$request = \Config\Services::request();

// Get full segment url after domain
$url = $request->getPath();

// search for slash in segment url
$pos = strrpos($url, '/');

// ternary if slash found return last segment including last slash
$last_seg = $pos === false ? $url : substr($url, $pos + 0);
```

Comment: It may works, but i'm sure there are more simple solutions.