# How to get last two uri segments in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to last two uri segment. just for example i have one url like:

`www.abcd.com/country/state/city`  AND Next time this url is dynamic so like this:

```
www.abcd.com/grade/country/state/city
```

i want to last two uri segments, please help and solve this problem.

Comment: I hope this answer will solve your problem and concept as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829781/code-igniter-get-last-uri-segment

Answer (score 2):

Yaah, i have found solution of this problem

```
$record_num = $this->uri->segment_array();
echo "last - ".$record_num[count($record_num)];
echo "<br>second last - ".$record_num[count($record_num)-1];
exit;
```

Comment: This is g8 solution when our url is dynamic when we don't know how much parameter in our url

Comment: yaah, Thanks, i want that type of solution which using in dynamic url.

Comment: can you find the solution for this question?if you remember please tell me?thanks in advance.

Comment: @attaafridi: i have already mentioned the answer in this comment. please check and let me know if need to more help

Answer (score 1):

You can use uri segments like so. Any thing after `www.abcd.com/` is a uri segment

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1); // This should echo grade

echo $this->uri->segment(2); // This should echo country

echo $this->uri->segment(3); // This should echo state

echo $this->uri->segment(4); // This should echo city
```

Segment [userguide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri%20segments#CI_URI::segment)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using

```
if ($this->uri->segment(1) == "country") {
    echo $this->uri->segment(2); //  echo state

    echo $this->uri->segment(3); //   echo city
}
if ($this->uri->segment(1) == "grade") {
    echo $this->uri->segment(3); //  echo state

    echo $this->uri->segment(4); //   echo city
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but, i have found short way to get uri segment.